# Unity has a broken ui on one user but not another

Tags: unity, login, users

My main admin account works fine with unity but when I login with my LFS account I made from the LFS tutorials which are a "standard" account type it's broken. When I click and drag on the desktop there is no highlight. The little controls center gear icon on the top right doesn't work when clicked and every app I open from the launcher will say its open but there is nothing on screen. Interestingly enough the apps are actually open. I opened terminal and blindly typed reboot and ubuntu rebooted so the windows are just invisible. I have pretty amature beginner experience with ubuntu and Linux in general.